# Is this an appositive?

Tags: grammar

> Keep up the great work you're doing, fighting for both animal and human rights.

And is following sentence grammatically correct?

> Keep up the great work, fighting for both animal and human rights.

Comment: Grammatically fine, but there's no apposition. Appositive modifiers are always noun phrases, not clauses.

Comment: It depends on the definition of 'apposition' you choose. Hanan Khatab Omar, in ['Apposition in English: A syntactic Study in Narrative and Scientific Texts'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332513870_Apposition_in_English_A_syntactic_Study_in_Narrative_and_Scientific_Texts), is reported in a very unconvincing way, but points to respected linguists using broader definitions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an appositive, but a supplement. In appositives, the appositive dependent itself could be substituted for the whole noun phrase without changing the meaning (CaGEL p447). In this case however,

> Keep up the great work you're doing, fighting for both animal and human rights.
>
> *Keep up fighting for both animal and human rights

Clearly the dependent cannot be substituted for the whole noun phrase.

Supplements do not have a direct grammatical connection to the element they are anchored to, and hence are separated from it by a pause in speech or a comma in writing.

In this case *fighitng for...* is a supplement to *the great work you're doing*

Both sentences are grammatical as head noun *work* is an acceptable anchor for *fighting for...*

In order for there to be a direct connection between the two, there would have to be a preposition inserted, and the order of the elements in the clause would change.

> Keep up the great work **of** fighting for both animal and human rights
> that you're doing.